# Convergence of complex numbers with barycentric appearance

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $\{{t_n\}}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ 
be a sequence of positive numbers with $(t_1+t_2+.....+t_n)\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$ and

$\{{z_n\}}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ a convergent to $A\ne\infty$ sequence of complex numbers, i.e.

$z_n\to A$.

Prove that 
$$\frac{t_1z_1+t_2z_2+.....+t_nz_n}{t_1+t_2+.....t_n}\to A$$ when $n\to\infty$.

**NOTE**.- Could someone be so kind to tell me how to locate the post, appeared today,
 in which it is asked the following: 
$0< x,y,z$  and $xyz=1$; prove $$\frac{x^3+x^2}{1+x^2}+\frac{y^3+y^2}{1+y^2}+\frac{z^3+z^2}{1+z^2}\ge 3$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nt_kz_k}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}-A=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nt_kz_k-A\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k(z_k-A)}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k},
\end{align*}
so we can assume that $A=0$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Then there is some $K\in\mathbb N$ such that $|z_k|<\epsilon$ for each $k\geq K$. For all $n\geq K$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nt_kz_k}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}\right|\leq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k|z_k|}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}t_k|z_k|+\epsilon\sum_{k=K}^nt_k}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}\leq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{K-1}t_k|z_k|}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}+\epsilon,
\end{align*}
and this goes to $\epsilon$ as $n\to\infty$, since $\sum_{k=1}^nt_k\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nt_kz_k}{\sum_{k=1}^nt_k}\right|\leq\epsilon,
\end{align*}
and letting $\epsilon\to0$ yields the desired result.